# Calculate IN-OUT Time for each employe

Tags: mysql

i have this table that has the time in and time out of employee. the problem is my time in and time out is in one column only. which is in FILO method First in and last out of time in and time out of employee.

employee time in time out table

the sample time like 0347 . means 03:47  .. or 1916 means 19:16. military time

```
id | emp_id |     date    | time
 1 |  GP1   | 2014-08-11  | 0847
 2 |  GP3   | 2014-08-11  | 0910
 3 |  GP2   | 2014-08-11  | 0912
 4 |  GP1   | 2014-08-11  | 1247
 5 |  GP2   | 2014-08-11  | 1756
 6 |  GP3   | 2014-08-11  | 1634
 7 |  GP1   | 2014-08-11  | 1650
```

now i want to make it like

```
id | emp_id |     date    | time in | time out
 1 |  GP1   | 2014-08-11  | 0847    |  1650
 2 |  GP2   | 2014-08-11  | 0912    |  1756
 3 |  GP3   | 2014-08-11  | 0910    |  1634
```

Comment: What does `id` mean in the result set? And take a look at MIN and MAX

Comment: OK. Get rid of it. And see MIN and MAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
emp_id, date, min(time), max(time)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY emp_id, date;
```

I'd recommend that you store your times in a column with datatype time. Or better, combine the column in a datetime or timestamp column. And don't name columns like keywords or function names.